# vim-fireplace Connect command won't run

Tags: vim, plugins, clojure

I've installed vim-fireplace, but the Connect command doesn't work. The error message is "Not an editor command: Connect". This leads me to believe I've messed up the installation but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

This is what I did:

I installed pathogen.
Then I ran these commands to install fireplace:

> cd ~/.vim/bundle
>
> git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace.git
>
> git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-classpath.git
>
> git clone git://github.com/guns/vim-clojure-static.git

This is my .vimrc
http://pastebin.com/7Mfk7xJD

Comment: Why have you commented out the line `filetype plugin indent on`? You want to have that active at all times.

Comment: Can you do `:h fireplace`?

Comment: Yes :h fireplace works. I commented out the the filetype plugin indent on because I got an error message about it after installing pathogen. No idea why.

Comment: Can you post your vimrc on stackoverflow so we can see it without going to an external site

Answer (score 8):

You will likely find that it works after you do `:set filetype=clojure`. The plugin is only active when editing clojure files or when you run this command.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar trouble, but found an answer in a blog posting and add my comments here:

http://cooljure.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-set-up-clojure-nrepl-using-vim.html

I am using Fedora 18, and the key seems to be that you need to create a project first using "lein new ", then begin both the vim edit session and the "lein repl" from within the project directory. Example:

```
> lein new fire
> cd fire
> lein repl
> gvim src/fire/core.clj
```

Besides installing vim-fireplace, vim-clojure-static, and vim-classpath, I also installed rainbow_parenthesis.vim as suggested by Tim Pope (author of fireplace).  I first installed vim-pathgen to handle the vim runtime path setup.  All of this is available on GitHub, starting at https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace

Alan Thompson

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and was able to run `:Connect` after (temporarily) removing everything from the .vimrc file except these three lines

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
execute pathogen#infect()
```

Now I will start restoring step-by-step the rest of .vimrc until I found the "culprit".